# Is it possible to attach a click event to a document fragment?

Tags: javascript

What I have tried:

```
// creating elements
var container = document.createDocumentFragment();
var headline = document.createElement('h1');
headline.innerHTML = 'This is a headline.';

// attaching to DOM
container.appendChild(headline);
document.body.appendChild(container);

// attaching click event
container.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

This example does not work. The event is not triggered.

**Is there any way to attach a click event to a document fragment or is it simply not possible?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The click event will not work in this case because document fragment is not appended to DOM structure. Here is what [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) says about it:

> Various other methods can take a document fragment as an argument (e.g., any Node interface methods such as [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) and [Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)), in which case the children of the fragment are appended or inserted, not the fragment itself.

So "children of the fragment are appended, not fragment itself". It means that click event bound to fragment is pretty much useless, because being outside of the DOM it's not reachable for clicks.

Comment: what do you mean "it wont work"? it's just impossible to click on, but if it was possible, eg, container.dispatchEvent(new Event("click")); it should still work.

Comment: @hanshenrik Of course, but I thought we were talking about appendChild behavior. In any case if you feel that it's important to add `dispatchEvent` then post the answer, I think it would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things preventing your code from working

### Events and `DocumentFragment`

First, as @dfsq said, the value of `container` is a `DocumentFragment`. When you call `appendChild` later, the contents of the `DocumentFragment` are moved into the DOM, but the fragment itself is not. That means the event listener is "left behind", and won't ever be triggered by a click.

The solution is to **attach the event listener to one of the children of `container`**, like `headline`:

```js
headline.addEventListener('click', ...
```

Often you don't have a direct reference, [like if you're working with templates and `.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template). In many cases the fragment only contains one element, so using `container.firstElementChild` is a good way to go. If your fragment were more complex, you might need to use `.querySelector` or something similar.

```js
container.appendChild(headline);
container.firstElementChild.addEventListener('click', // ...
```

### `DocumentFragment` and `.appendChild`

Second, when you call `document.body.appendChild` [the contents of the `DocumentFragment` are *moved* into the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), and out of the fragment. The fragment doesn't retain a reference. The idea is that a node can't have two parents. That means that by the time you call `addEventListener`, there aren't any nodes for events to happen to!

The solution is to attach the event listener *before* calling `.appendChild`.

### Solution

Putting these two together gives the following implementation:

```js
// creating elements
var container = document.createDocumentFragment();
var headline = document.createElement('h1');
headline.innerHTML = 'This is a headline.';

// attaching click event
headline.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('click happened!');
});

// attaching to DOM
container.appendChild(headline);
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of how to create a fragment get one of html component and attach an event on it...

```
function createFragmentWithEvent(){
    let html = ` 
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; padding: 5px;">   
            <img style="width: 40px; height: 40px; " src="${value.profilPicture_}"></img>
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; font-size: .85em; padding-left: 8px;">
                <span>${value._id}</span>
                <span>${value.email_}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <paper-button style="font-size:.65em; width: 20px; align-self: flex-end;" id="${value._id}_invite_btn">Invite</paper-button>
    </div>`
    let range = document.createRange()
    let fragment = range.createContextualFragment(html)
    let inviteBtn = fragment.getElementById(value._id + "_invite_btn")
    inviteBtn.onclick = ()=>{
        console.log("----> invite ", value)
    }
}
```